# PHP throws a message failed to open stream

Tags: php

I am trying to copy file from my local machine to Windows server.

```
$local_dir = 'C:\Users\host\Pictures\Camera Roll'; //source url
$local_server_dir = '\\10.1.0.1\new'; //destination url the ip is
```

The segment that I use to copy the image is

```
copy("$local_dir/$files[$i]","$local_server_dir/$name")
```

recursively using for loop, but the system throw a warning as mention below.

> Warning: copy(\10.1.0.1\new/IMG_1844.JPG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\image\index.php on line 22

What can I try to investigate the cause of this?

Comment: $files is an array which hold source url images names

Comment: Does the process that PHP is running under have permission to access that server and share?

Comment: yes i do have a permission

Comment: I'm sorry, but when you say it like that, it sounds like either you have permission as in "it is my server so of course I'm allowing it", or you that you, Micky, can access that share on your Windows machine, neither of which is what I'm asking. I apologize if I'm misunderstanding you, or possibly insulting you, that isn't my intention, I just want to make sure it is clear what we're talking about.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Your error message may be indicating that your backslashes in the string expression need to be escaped. Try doubling them up to `'\\\\10.1.0.1\\new'`. This is because each slash needs a preceding slash in order to show PHP that a backlash was required (and not an escape sequence instead).

Comment: Failing that you could always map a drive so that you can access the file via a drive letter instead.